# How do I get this lightning fast search?

Tags: php, mysql, search, search-engine

I just came over this site: http://www.hittaplagget.se. If you enter the following search word `moo`, the autosuggest pops up immediately.

But if you go to my site, http://storelocator.no, and use the same search phrase (in "Search for brand" field), it takes a lot longer for autosuggest to suggest anything.

I know that we can only guess on what type of technology they are using, but hopefully someone here can do an educational guess better than I can.

In my solution I only do a `SELECT moo% FROM table` and return the results.
I have yet not indexed my table as there are only 7000 rows in it. But I'm thinking of indexing my tables using Lucene.

Can anyone suggest what I need to do in order to get equally fast autosuggest?

Comment: You're about 500ms slower than them.

Comment: for fastest possible search, autocomplete results should not be retrieved via query, but via a local JS array; check jQuery autocomplete. If a query must be made, then attempt to optimize at sql level. May be other factors at play, they have superior hardware, better network latency (due to multi-servers around the world), etc.

Comment: The comment above suggests to send all 7000 items via javascript before even knowing if the user will be doing a search, and even if he does i would strongly suggest not doing that.

Comment: Yeah, reading 7000+ rows into an javascript array is not the way to go.

Comment: agreed, OP is wanting lightning fast, however; thus the suggestion.  If he is really concerned about live-query speed, with a 7,000 record set, he "should" go with an in-memory DB

Comment: @Hary, I'm using jQuery.get for quering DB.
@virtualeyes, I know I get "lightning fast" if everything is in memory, but loading "huge" amount of data in to memory is not good practice.

Answer (score 4):

You must add an index on the column holding your search terms, even at 7000 - otherwise, the database searching through the whole list every time.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html.

Answer (score 1):

Lucene is a full text search index and may or may not be what you're looking for. Lucene would find any occurrence of "moo" in the entire indexed column (e.g. Mootastic and Fantasticmoo) and does not necessarily speed up your search although it's faster than a where x like '%moo%' type of search.

As others have already pointed out a regular index (probably even unique?) is what you want if you're performing "starts with" type of searches.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to table-scan the table, so I suggest:

- Don't put any rows in the table you don't need - for example, "inactive" records - keep them in a different table
- Don't put any columns in the table you don't need
- You can achieve this by having a special "Search table" which just contains the rows/columns you're interested in, and updating it from the "Master table".

Table-scanning a 7000 row table should be extremely efficient if the rows are small; I understand from your problem domain that this will be the case.

But as others have pointed out - don't send the 7000 rows to the client-side when it doesn't need it.

A conventional index can optimise a LIKE 'someprefix%' into a range-scan, so it is probably helpful having one. If you want to search for the string in any part of the entry, it is going to be a table-scan (which should not be slow on such a tiny table!)